# How to host multiple Angular apps, subdomained w/ nginx container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, devops

So my situation is as follows - I have two bundled Angular apps, residing inside of a Docker Container. I want to host them at separate subdomains (app1.example.com & app2.example.com, or for now app1.localhost:8000 and app2.localhost:8000) using the same nginx config.

Currently I'm bundling them and sticking them inside of separate directories,

```
COPY --from=web-build-stage /app/dist/first-app/ /usr/share/nginx/html/first
COPY --from=web-build-stage /app/dist/second-app/ /usr/share/nginx/html/second
```

and my nginx config is broken into two servers as follows -

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name first.localhost;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/first
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name second.localhost;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/second
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

I've also updated my host file as such -

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   first.localhost
127.0.0.1   second.localhost
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why it's either not proxying properly or where I'm going wrong on the config.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears I've found my own answer, and it was a lame miss on my part.

Working config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name first.localhost;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/first;
  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name second.localhost;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/second;
  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Notice: I moved the `root` out of each `location` block (noted [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)), and they NEEDED a semi-colon at the end of the path. Don't miss that!